# Grub2 boot loader doesn't appear on boot

Tags: 10.10, grub2

Okay, install goes smoothly every time.  No issues on that end.  I let Ubuntu decide where to place the boot loader.  It's usually */dev/sda*.

The issue I have is the boot loader. Grub, does not show up when I boot my machine.  It automatically boots into Ubuntu without any action from my part.  So I do not see a Grub2 prompt.

Should I have installed the boot loader into a different partition to get the Grub menu appear on boot?

Answer (score 4):

Hold the shift key down as you boot and you will get a menu.

If you want to change that behavior, you need to edit /etc/default/grub

```
# Graphical
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub

# Command line
sudo -e /etc/default/grub
```

And comment out `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` (add a # at the front of the line)

Like this

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

See : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Hidden

Save your edit and then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

If you wish, you can install [StartUpManager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/StartUpManager) which gives you a graphical method of configuring grub

[image: Startupmanager]

Comment: Thank you so much!  Your quick response is much appreciated!

Comment: @Brogan If it solved your problem you might want to consider marking it as answered by clicking the green check mark next to the answer.