# Grub doesn't show both Ubuntu installations

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, ubuntu-studio

I have a laptop with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed as the main OS. The other day I installed Ubuntu-Studio (version 12.04) into another partition on the machine.

The installation went great and when the machine booted, the grub menu popped up and I could see the option for Ubuntu Studio and the vanilla Ubuntu OS'. The problem was that this version of grub, installed by the Studio installer, didn't look great and insisted on putting Studio at the top of the list, and therefore as the main OS to boot.

I use the standard Ubuntu more often, so I booted into that and ran `sudo grub-install  dev/sda`. That worked OK and now Ubuntu boots as normal. Only problem is that the Grub menu doesn't show up and doesn't give me a chance to choose the other OS. Running `sudo os-prober` shows that it *can* find ubuntu studio, it doesn't give me a chance to boot it.

Any ideas as to how I can fix this problem?

Cheers in advance.

EDIT:
followed instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100954/grub2-boot-loader-doesnt-appear-on-boot) and saw the boot menu, but the only boot options present were for the standard installation of Ubuntu.

Comment: I think [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/100954/grub2-boot-loader-doesnt-appear-on-boot) is what you're looking for.

Comment: I followed those instructions, but grub only showed boot choices for the standard ubuntu installation... I'll add that to the question. Thanks for that though!

Comment: Do you mean that you see exactly one row, say "Ubuntu 12.04 LTS" or that you see 2 rows, with the first similar to "Ubuntu 12.04 LTS" and the second similar to "Previous Linux versions" or "Advanced options for [...]"?

Comment: Ok, but the os-prober is executed when you type `sudo update-grub` (e.g. as in [this](http://www.mikejonesey.co.uk/images2/grub-update.png) screenshot) or not?

Comment: turns out it wasn't; I had to chmod the /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober file to be executable. Thanks All!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I the os-prober utility wasn't executable. I had to run this:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/30_os-prober
```

and then

```
sudo update-grub2
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is so common.
Just  use the command below in you Command Line.

```
sudo update-grub2
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Already done that several times with no success.

Comment: @jackweirdy, just because you somehow managed to disable `os-prober` doesn't make the answer a bad one.  You still needed to run `update-grub`.

Comment: I didn't downvote you if that's what you're thinking?

Comment: @jackweirdy, oh... then I'm left wondering who did and why.

Comment: @psusi I also didn't downvote you, but the possible reason may be, `sudo update-grub` can do nothing with the actual problem of not-recognizing other installation. yes, You're still correct that, he need that command though.